# StringUtils.isBlank vs. Regexp

Tags: java, regex, string, apache-stringutils

So I am looking through some legacy code and finding instance where they do this:

```
if ((name == null) || (name.matches("\\s*")))
   .. do something
```

Ignore for the moment that the `.matches(..)` call creates a new Pattern and Matcher everytime (uhg) - but is there any reason not to change this line to:

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(name))
   ..do something
```

I'm pretty sure the regex simply matches if the string is all whitespace.  Will StringUtils catch all the same conditions as the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `StringUtils.isBlank(..)` will do the same thing, and is a better way to go. Take a look at the code:

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
     int strLen;
     if ((str == null) || ((strLen = str.length()) == 0))
         return true;
     int strLen;
     for (int i = 0; i < strLen; ++i) {
        if (!(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)))) {
           return false;
        }
     }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the regular expression test's if the string is more zero or more white space characters.

The advantages of not using the regular expression

- Regular expressions are cryptic to many people, which makes it less readable
- And as you rightly pointed out `.matches()` has a non trivial overhead

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Returns if the specified string is <code>null</code> or the empty string.
 * @param string the string
 * @return <code>true</code> if the specified string is <code>null</code> or the empty string, <code>false</code> otherwise
 */
public static boolean isEmptyOrNull(String string)
{
    return (null == string) || (0 >= string.length());
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. OP wants to know if the string has white space or is null. `string.length() =< 0` would return false if string was '   ' Though that is an empty string and should return true in your method, it would return false since it is neither null nor the length =< 0. IF you REALLY didn't want to use the `StringUtils.isBlank()` (which you should) your return statement should be `return (null == string) || (0 >= string.trim().length());` The `.trim()` cuts off all blank space on the outside of the method. i.e.: `"  hi hello  ".trim()` would be equivalent to "hi hello"